# Where can the Longman communication 3000 (most common spoken and written words) just starting on 2000?

Tags: vocabulary

I want to review my vocabulary by checking the longman list of most spoken and written  words from 2000 to 3000 (from 1 to 2000 I assume I know). Here I found the complete list:

http://www.lextutor.ca/freq/lists_download/longman_3000_list.pdf

I wanted the 2000 to 3000 separated from the other ones.

Comment: Possibly this question should be moved to meta or some other site.

Answer (score 3):

To select words in the range 2000-3000 from that list, you can first copy all the entries into a text file, and then select all the relevant *S3* entries into another file.

To copy all the entries into a text file, press control-a in the PDF file, then click the middle mouse button in a text-editor window (that is, a program-editing-editor window, not a word-processor window).  (On some systems you might need to instead press control-c and control-v, or  might need to select Copy and Paste from right-mouse-button drop-down menus or from application menus.)  Then save the text file, eg in `longman-3000`.

To copy relevant *S3* entries into another text file, enter a command like

```
egrep 'S3$|S3,' longman-3000 > longman-2000-3000
```

On my system, longman-2000-3000 ends up as a file with 999 entries in it, beginning and ending as follows:

> absence n S3, W2
>   acceptable adj S3, W3
>   account v S3, W2
>   achievement n S3, W2
>   ...
>   worse adv S3, W3
>   wrap v S3
>   writer n S3, W2
>   youngster n S3

Comment: Yes, the counts are odd.  S1=997, W1=998; S2=1000, W2=1000; S3=999, W3=999.